# How to resolve sonatype-2017-0312 vulnerability

Tags: java, security, jackson-databind

Sonatype Nexus IQ Server component scan states that Jackson-Databind version 2.9.9 library has Vulnerability issue coded as sonatype-2017-0312.

jackson-databind is vulnerable to Remote Code Execution (RCE). The createBeanDeserializer() function in the BeanDeserializerFactory class allows untrusted Java objects to be deserialized. A remote attacker can exploit this by uploading a malicious serialized object that will result in RCE if the application attempts to deserialize it.

I have tried to use redhat version of Jackson-databind and different types that has recommended by sonatype but at last we are now facing now using jackson-databind-2.9.8.redhat-00004.jar and ended with two vulnerability CVE-2019-12086 and sonatype-2017-0312.

Comment: CVSS v3.0 Severity and Metrics:
Base Score: 7.5 HIGH 
Vector: AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:N/A:N
Impact Score: 3.6 
Exploitability Score: 3.9

Attack Vector (AV): Network 
Attack Complexity (AC): Low 
Privileges Required (PR): None 
User Interaction (UI): None 
Scope (S): Unchanged 
Confidentiality (C): High 
Integrity (I): None 
Availability (A): None https://www.first.org/cvss/specification-document

Answer (score 0):

As a solution is to set gson for preferred-json-mapper as alternative json implementation provider.

For maven dependency management:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are other ones as well:
Jackson Library, Google-Gson Library, JSON-lib, Flexjson, json-io, genson, JSONiJ Library.

Answer (score 0):

Don't abandon Jackson because there is a vulnerability;
that is ridiculous.

Just upgrade the version of Jackson databind on which your project depends
to a version that resolves the vulnerability.
For example,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```